# single-column or composite index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

For a table like this

```
[  col1   -   col2   -   col3   -   col4 ]
[    1    -     2    -     3     -    4  ]
```

I'm going to use two types of queries in two cases

One is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col3 = 3;`

Another is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col4 = 4;`

In this case, Do I make a

`composite index` for `col1 AND col2` only and a `single-column index` for `col3 AND col4`

or do I go

`ALL` columns `single-column index`

or put

`ALL` the columns in `composite index`

Side question: Do I have to name the Index? And what is the Index size?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have these two:

```
INDEX col123 (col1, col2, col3),
INDEX col214 (col2, col1, col4)
```

Notes:

- For the 2 queries given, it does not matter which order the 3 columns are in the composite queries.
- I did col1 and col2 in different orders just in case some *other* query needs `col2` without `col1`.
- Having `INDEX(col3)` (single-column) is less useful.
- With `INDEX(col1, col2), INDEX(col3)` -- The optimizer will pick one index and not use the other.  This is less good than having an index with all three columns.
- Luke is good; [*my index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) might be better?
- The "rules of thumb" are aimed at Postgres.  Do *not* use them; there are too many things that are incorrect for MySQL.
- The "query tuning" link is aimed at DB2; it *mostly* applies to MySQL.
- `INSERTs` do take a little time to update the index(es), but most of that work is delayed (see "Change buffering") for non-UNIQUE indexes.  Don't let that stop you from adding an index.  The benefit on a `SELECT` *usually* far outweighs the cost in `INSERT`.
- Index names are optional in MySQL, but the default for a composite index can be misleading.

Another way to compare queries and/or indexes, even with too few rows to get reliable timings:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Big numbers = bad; small numbers = smile.

Answer (score 0):

A compound index on col1 and col2, with single-column indexes on col3 and col4 is *probably* going to work best. But the way to tell for certain is to build a table for testing, and populate it with sample data. If possible, insert roughly the same amount of data you expect in production.

Then build indexes, run the queries, and read the execution plans. Drop the indexes, build them a different way, run the queries, and read the execution plans.

You should also think about what other queries need to use this table, and how indexes affect those queries. Think about INSERT and DELETE queries as well as SELECT statements.

Whether you have to name the index depends on the dbms. Most of them will supply a system-generated name if you leave it out. The size of the index depends on the dbms; there's usually a way to figure it out if the dbms doesn't supply explicit functions or stored procedures to do that.

Comment: How would indexing affect the INSERT? I thought it is about the UPDATE and SELECT

Comment: @CaliburVictorious: Some or all of the indexes for a table have to be updated when you insert rows. This *usually* isn't a problem, but it does take more time. More indexes, more time. More columns in the indexes, more time. Some applications can be pretty sensitive to that increase in time.

Comment: Can you please tell me then What type of rows i usually need to index and what not to index? Since i use for example from 1 to 4 rows to fetch some data But to update it i use 1, And to insert i use 1 to 3, In this case do index all the rows if more than 1, Or just one important row used a lot?

Comment: [Use the index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) is a highly respected site for learning indexing in general. I've posted short [Rules of Thumb for indexing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31517/1064) and on [query tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49568/1064) on DBA.